appsheetとGoogle Cloud for MySQLを接続したい
・解決したいこと
appsheetで製作途中のアプリと、
Google Cloud for MySQL内に作成したデータベースを接続したい
・発生している問題・エラー
接続に失敗しました
・試したことなど
Appsheetの +Newconnect から以下の画像のように入力し接続を試しましたが失敗します。
ユーザー名はユーザー名とサービスアカウント名どちらも試しました。
SSLは無しにしています。
環境はWindows11です。

・ネット検索し試したことを以下に書きます。
①Google Cloud for MySQL内にて
・以下のAPIを有効にする
Cloud Dataplex API、Cloud Datastore API、Cloud Logging API、Cloud Monitoring API
Cloud OS Login API、Cloud Resource Manager API、Cloud SQL、Cloud SQL Admin API
Cloud Storage、Cloud Storage API、Cloud Trace API、Dataform API、Google Cloud APIs
Google Cloud Storage JSON API、Service Management API、Service Usage API
Cloud Identity-Aware Proxy API、Compute Engine API
・インスタンス、ユーザー、ユーザーのパスワード、サービスアカウント、サービスアカウントのキー（json）の作成
・データベースの作成
②Appsheet上にて設定変更はしてません
補足
ネット検索しましたが、画像のように入力しても接続できない場合の対処法は見当たりませんでした。
アプリとデータベースを作成し始めて2か月の初心者です。
基本がわかっていないため解決できないように感じています。
宜しくお願い致します。

teratail や Qiita でも同じ内容の投稿をされているようですが、予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうとスムーズに回答が付きやすくなると思います。 / 参考: マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？
